# How can I make drops of fluid hang from a surface?

Tags: fluid-simulation

The images below display the kind of effect that I'm looking for. A combination of surface tension and intermolecular forces make drops of water hang on things (though they may occasionally fall off depending on the amount of fluid in the drop). I can't seem to figure out how to do this with the fluid simulator though--every time I try, the fluid just beads off like the object is made of a hydrophobic material; as soon as it reaches the side of the obstacle, it falls, rather than curving to the surface like my diagram.

[image: example 3]

[image: example 1][image: example 2]

I've already tried using various combinations of `No Slip`, `Partial Slip`, and `Free Slip` on both the obstacle and the domain but I can't find the right combination.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that if you want to do this for a still, it is almost certainly going to be better to fake it.

Comment: @VRM That's disappointing; I was hoping for a decent generalized solution. If one can't be given, ideally, I would like to see answers for both animated and static blends. Could you elaborate on how you would go about in creating an accurate fake?

Comment: There is no quick way to do this in animation. For a still, the particle system and some hand modelled droplets would do. For an animation; if the fluid system doesn't work out for you, maybe try with a particle system with metaballs and dynamic paint like in this link: https://blenderartists.org/t/looking-for-recommendations-rain-on-glass/535569

Answer (score 9):

Apply a strength 5 force field to both the fluid and obstacle. The fluid should probably have a low partial slip, and free flip on the object. I would be more precise if I had more time, but here's my result (see below pic). You can see particles starting to stick, then fall off near the very bottom.
[image]

How it works: Water molecules have a charge of attraction to each other (and solid objects) causing surface tension, which holds a drop together. applying the force field tries to imitate that effect.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use fluid sim you can also keyframe the speed value, changing from 1 to 0 (no motion), in the fluid sim panel as it's shown below.

[image]

Anoter way is to model a drop, halve it and use as hair particles with vertex groups.

Answer (score 2):

The best way that I know of to do this, assuming you just want a still, is to do it through metaballs.  Set up the object with the metaballs so that they diffuse onto the glass, but remain off from it enough to look like a droplet.  If you do multiple of them, you can animate them, although it will not look the most realistic.  Alternatively, use this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO8kw0a2ZeI on how to make a rainy window, and apply it to the effect that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to create a Fluid Simulation and grab the Key Frame from it.
There is an Add-On called FLIPFluids but it is $76 https://www.blendermarket.com/products/flipfluids.

Twitter Link: https://twitter.com/FlipFluids

I've never used it but I've seen some amazing examples.